# How to redirect user to another page after Ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, redirect

I'm having problems redirecting the user to a thank you page after a successful form completion. What happens is that after the form submits, it goes to a blank page (https://cunet.sparkroom.com/Sparkroom/postLead)... I need it to redirect to a thank you page while submitting the form details to the URL in the 'form action'.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="https://cunet.sparkroom.com/Sparkroom/postLead/" method="post" name="theForm" 
id="theForm" onSubmit="return MM_validateForm();" >
...
</form>
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
           alert('form was submitted');
        }); 
     success:function(response) {
           location.window.href = "redirect user to the thank you page";
                }
    }); 
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MM_validateForm() {
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #FirstName').val() ) {
alert('Please input your first name.');
jQuery('#theForm #FirstName').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #LastName').val() ) {
alert('Please input your last name.');
jQuery('#theForm #LastName').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #daytimephone').val() ) {
alert('Please input your phone number.');
jQuery('#theForm #daytimephone').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #Email').val() ) {
alert('Please input your email.');
jQuery('#theForm #Email').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #BID').val() ) {
alert('Please select your preferred campus.');
jQuery('#theForm #BID').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #programs').val() ) {
alert('Please select your preferred program.');
jQuery('#theForm #programs').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #How_Heard').val() ) {
alert('Please select how you heard about us.');
jQuery('#theForm #How_Heard').focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
// ]]></script>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I need the form to submit the data to the URL and then after redirect the user to a 'thank you' page

Answer (score 18):

Your success callback syntax is incorrect. It should rather be:

```
$('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    window.location.href = "/path/to/thankyoupage";
});
```

Also, note that it is `window.location.href` and not `location.window.href`

Comment: I just tried the code but it does not redirect the user to the desired page, instead it just successfully submits the data to the URL but it does not redirect thereafter :(!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

and not

```
location.window.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

The success should be a the functtion passed as an argument to $.ajaxForm:

```
$('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
           window.location.href = "redirect user to the thank you page";
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a jQUery Solution:

```
window.location("www.example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Please try this    
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
               alert('form was submitted');
            }); 
         success:function(response) {
               if(response){ // check whether response is received
                    location.window.href = "http://your_domain_name/thank-you";}
               }
        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The follow code worked for me, in a complete different context of the OP:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.location.href = "URL";
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this :

```
 success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = data.redirecturl;
},
error: function () {
    alert('error happened');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Should be

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```