# How to redirect user to another page after Ajax form submission?

Tags: java, html, ajax, forms

I'm having problems redirecting the user to a thank you page after a successful form completion. What happens is that after the form submits, it goes to a blank page (https://cunet.sparkroom.com/Sparkroom/postLead)... I need it to redirect to a thank you page while submitting the form details to the URL in the 'form action'.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="https://cunet.sparkroom.com/Sparkroom/postLead/" method="post" name="theForm" 
id="theForm" onSubmit="return MM_validateForm();" >
...
</form>
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script> 
    $('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    window.location.href = "I want the user to be redirected to this page";
});
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MM_validateForm() {
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #FirstName').val() ) {
alert('Please input your first name.');
jQuery('#theForm #FirstName').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #LastName').val() ) {
alert('Please input your last name.');
jQuery('#theForm #LastName').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #daytimephone').val() ) {
alert('Please input your phone number.');
jQuery('#theForm #daytimephone').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #Email').val() ) {
alert('Please input your email.');
jQuery('#theForm #Email').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #BID').val() ) {
alert('Please select your preferred campus.');
jQuery('#theForm #BID').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #programs').val() ) {
alert('Please select your preferred program.');
jQuery('#theForm #programs').focus();
return false;
}
if ( !jQuery('#theForm #How_Heard').val() ) {
alert('Please select how you heard about us.');
jQuery('#theForm #How_Heard').focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
// ]]></script>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I need the form to submit the data to the URL and then after redirect the user to a 'thank you' page, right now that is not at all happening.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using Ajax if you going to redirect the user to a thank you page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect user to another page after Ajax form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748283/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-after-ajax-form-submission)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
window.location.href = "http://www.msdn.com";
```

Comment: This implies HTTP Get request form submission is Post.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
 success : function(){
    window.location.href = "Url to redirect here in the success option";
 }
});
```

Comment: Nice! That worked like a charm for me! :) After reading 10+ questions with saving windows and alike. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to redirect user after successful form post.

1) You can put a on Success event in ajax submission in which you can simply redirect user to thankyou page.

2) Use a server side function after your form post processing done
   For Ex in PHP:

```
header("Location: http://thankyoupage.html");
```

Comment: How would I be able to do option 1? Do you have any code to provide examples with?

Comment: Add these line in your validation function.

var url = "https://cunet.sparkroom.com/Sparkroom/postLead";
var data = jQuery('#theForm').serialize();
jQuery.ajax( {
   url : url,
   type : 'post',
   data : data,
   success : function() {
    window.location.href = "http://thankyou.com";
}
});

Answer (score 0):

You could hadle the submit post with jquery, so you will have to cancel the action in the form

```
    <form  name="theForm" id="theForm" >
```

just give a class or ID to the submit button

```
    <submit class='submitTheForm'....>
```

the code will be like this.. you just need to include all the form variables with the right name.

Then add the jquery post request at the bottom of MM_validateForm()

```
    if ( !jQuery('#theForm #How_Heard').val() ) {
    alert('Please select how you heard about us.');
    jQuery('#theForm #How_Heard').focus();
    return false;
    }

    $.post("https://cunet.sparkroom.com/Sparkroom/postLead/",
{
FirstName:FirstName,
LastName:LastName
    ...
    ...
},
function(){
    window.location.href = 'thank you page'
    }
});
```

And finally call the function MM_validateForm() when the submit button get clicked

```
    $('.submitTheForm').click( function(){
    MM_validateForm();
    });
```

jquery post from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ the rest from personal experience.