# Execute window.location redirect AFTER ajax is complete

Tags: php, jquery

In summary, I have a form that is loaded via AJAX. Required fields for this form are checked via another AJAX call.  Once all required fields have been filled, a new record is added to db and the user should NOW be sent to my payment page to complete the application process.  I have tried adding `window.location = "http://www.paymentPage.php";` but no matter where I place this code, it is executing along with my ajax code.  I even tried adding a `die(header:location('paymentPage.php'));` at the end of my code in validMA.php.  I know I'm missing something simple...just can't figure it out.

PHP code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('header.htm');?>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="container">
   <div id="content"><div class="content">
      <h1>New Member Application</h1>
   <form method="post" name="checkUserMA" id="checkUserMA">
    <label class="clear" style="width:120px">Username/Email<br><span class="small"></span></label>
    <input type="text" name="usernameMA" id="usernameMA" class="green" style="width:300px;"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="checkUserMA" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <div id="errorMA"></div>
    <div id="resultMA"></div>
    </div></div><!--end content-->  
<div id="footer">
<?php include("footer.htm") ?>
<!--<?php include("disclaimer.htm") ?>-->
</div><!--end footer-->
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--end container-->
<div class="clear"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //NEW MEMBER APPLICATION
    $('#resultMA').hide();
    $('#errorMA').hide();
    $("#checkUserMA").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#resultMA").html('');
        var values = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkMA.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            success: function(result){
                $("#resultMA").html(result).fadeIn();
                $('.error').hide();
                validMA();
                window.location = "http://184.154.174.162/~nsgpcom/memberAppPay.php";
            },
            error:function(){
               $("#resultMA").html('There was an error.').fadeIn();
            }
        });//end ajax
    });
function validMA(){
    $("#fullFormMA").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#errorMA").html('');
        var fullForm = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "validMA.php",
            type: "post",
            data: fullForm,
            success: function(result){
                $("#errorMA").html(result).fadeIn();
            },
            error:function(){
               $("#errorMA").html('There was an error.  Please try again.').fadeIn();
            }
        });//end 
    });
    $("errorMA").hide();
}//end function
```

validMA.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('functions.php');
connect();
$firstName = protect($_POST['firstName']); 
$lastName = protect($_POST['lastName']);
$address1 = protect($_POST['address1']);
$address2 = protect($_POST['address2']);
$city = protect($_POST['city']);
$state = protect(strtoupper($_POST['state']));
$zip = protect($_POST['zip']);
$required = array('firstName','lastName','address1','city','state','zip');
    // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}
if ($error){
    echo "You need to fill in all required (*) fields";
} else {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO newMembers (username,firstName,lastName,address1,address2,city,state,zip,publicEmail,workPhone,privateAddress1,privateAddress2,privateCity,privateState,privateZip,homePhone,cellPhone,website,facebook,twitter,linkedIn,education,licensure,certification,statement,dateAdded) VALUES ('$username','$firstName','$lastName','$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$zip','$publicEmail','$workPhone','$privateAddress1','$privateAddress2','$privateCity','$privateState','$privateZip','$homePhone','$cellPhone','$website','$facebook','$twitter','$linkedIn','$education','$licensure','$certification','$statement','$dateAdded')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
}?>
```

Hoping to understand this logic.  I know I will use it again and again.

Comment: you can also print out the error returned from your ajax call.
error: function(xhr, status, error){
console.log(error + " Error here");
}

and should be window.location.href = url;

Answer (score 0):

Your `window.location = ...` should be inside the `validMA` function

```
function validMA(){
    $("#fullFormMA").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#errorMA").html('');
        var fullForm = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "validMA.php",
            type: "post",
            data: fullForm,
            success: function(result){
                $("#errorMA").html(result).fadeIn();

                /* ====
                 * HERE YOU PLACE IT
                 * ====
                 */
                window.location = "http://184.154.174.162/~nsgpcom/memberAppPay.php";


            },
            error:function(){
               $("#errorMA").html('There was an error.  Please try again.').fadeIn();
            }
        });//end 
    });
    $("errorMA").hide();
}//end function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I had tried it there. What happens is as soon as I click into the form where I am attempting to validate several fields using validMA.php, I am immediately redirected to my payment page.  Yes, the redirection works there. But how do I COMPLETE all my validations BEFORE I transfer the user to the payment page?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
validMA();
window.location = "http://184.154.174.162/~nsgpcom/memberAppPay.php";
```

But I window.location goes inside that validMA();

```
success: function(result){
            $("#errorMA").html(result).fadeIn();
            window.location = "http://184.154.174.162/~nsgpcom/memberAppPay.php";
        },
```

In here!

Answer (score 0):

My problems using the suggestions above were that the user was redirected to the payment page before all validation was complete...actually upon the first form submission. I added the following code at the bottom of my validMA.php code (within the success portion of my if/else loop).

```
if ($error){
    echo "You need to fill in all required (*) fields";
} else {
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO newMembers (username,firstName,lastName,address1,address2,city,state.....)";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('You completed step 1');
        window.location.href = "http://www.paymentPage.php";
    </script>
<?php
}?>
```

I feel it is not as elegant as it could be, but it does work.  Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
window.location.href="your URL"
```

instead of

```
window.location
```

Comment: Before downvoting read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749144/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-after-ajax-form-submission

Comment: It may be better to explain *in* the answer why your solution works. You'll probably repeat some explanation in the link you provided, but it makes a better solution

Comment: Above there is syntax mistake so if i will explain that you have syntax mistake and how you will correct that then it would be spoon feeding. I dont agree for your downvote. You can downvote if answer is wrong.