# Redirecting after form submission in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, submit

I hope someone can assist with this. I dont have access to the website backend, so I cant change the js script uploaded there. What I am trying to achieve is make a simple form to submit an issue report and then display a "Thank you" popup and redirect back to main page of the account on our page.

So I can make a form no problem. I copied one of the functioning forms by going to Edit link and clicking on Show Source in Page Body. But I can't stop the default behavior of it going to another page after Submit button is pressed. I suspect it is in js script on the back end. I'll copy code below.

```
<center>
<b>App Issues Report Form</b>
<br>
</center>

<form action="/Modules/SendForm" method="post" class="form" id="NewForm">
<input name="formFields" value="CONTACTID,AgentName,Notes" type="hidden">
       <input name="formLabels" value="Contact ID:,Agent Name:,Notes:" type="hidden">
       <input name="fromAddress" value="no-reply@callcenter.com" type="hidden">
       <input name="toAddress" value="name@CallCenter.com" type="hidden">
       <input name="subject" value="A new message about app" type="hidden">
       <input name="emailMsg" value="The following data has been collected:" type="hidden">
       <input name="CONTACTID" value="##CONTACTID##" type="hidden">
<input name="companyId" value="##COMPANY_ID##" type="hidden">


                        <div class="clearfix">
                        <label>Agent Name:</label>
                        <div class="input"><input id="AgentName" name="AgentName"
 class="validate[required] xlarge" value="##LOGGEDIN_AGENT_FIRST_NAME## 
 ##LOGGEDIN_AGENT_LAST_NAME##" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="clearfix">
                        <label>Notes:</label>
                        <div class="input"><textarea id="Notes" name="Notes" 
class="validate[required] xxlarge"></textarea>
                        </div>
</div>
                    <div class="clearfix grey-highlight">
                    <div class="input no-label">
                        <input class="button blue" value="Submit" type="submit">
                        <input class="button grey" value="Reset" type="reset">
                    </div>
                </div>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("NewForm").click(function( event ) {
alert( "Thank you for your feedback" );
event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

It used to have only this at the end when I copied the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
new setupAjaxForm('NewForm'); }); 
</script>
```

I tried searching and suggestions here didnt seem to work:

[How to redirect user to another page after Ajax form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748283/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-after-ajax-form-submission)

[How to redirect user to another page after Ajax form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749144/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-after-ajax-form-submission)

http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: The title says [tag:java]. Did you mean [tag:javascript]?

Comment: I just corrected that, @MattBall ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to look at is `action="/Modules/SendForm"` - this is what does the redirection. If you don't want to redirect, set this to the name of the page you have the form. Obviously there is a whole lot more to forms and redirection (and some other js code might influence this too, nonetheless we don't see what the function `setupAjaxForm` is supposed to do here), but this is really the first thing to check / get right.

**EDIT:** I think I understand it more now: basically if you don't have access to the `/Modules/SendForm` page (where most probably, among others, like form validation, the redirection also happens, then you can't do much to change the redirection.

Comment: Thank you. Whereever the form is submitted to - it comes into my inbox nicely formatted with colored bars etc. I'd like to keep that feature going. I just need it to go to a different webpage after I hit Submit. And also after a popup saying Thank You...

Comment: Yes I dont have access to that Modules page... But I thought     event.preventDefault(); can stop the default behavior

Comment: Or can I just add a popup that a user has to click on before it goes to that default page?

Comment: The problem is that you just have to send the form to that other page, otherwise your validations and the nice email and all wouldn't happen, and that's probably where the redirection happens too. You can't control that unless you'd have access to the code; in that case you could actually copy it, put it on your own page and change the redirection URL.