# Redirect to a page using C# controller while using AJAX method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using C# ASP.NET MVC and wish to know is there any way to redirect to other page from controller in success condition. For failure condition, it should return JSon result redirect to AJAX method. For this, ActionResult return type is okay for me.

### C# Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoMyAction(string var1, string var2)
{
    // Do some action
    if(success)
        Redirect to a page.
    else
        return Json(new { Message = "Action cannot be process..", Status = false});
}
```

### AJAX method:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Home/DoMyAction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "var1": "Hello", "var2":"World!"},
        datatype: "json",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            if (!result.Status)
                // Display error message.
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
```

Note: Please do not consider syntax here, I wish to know only the way to redirect from C# controller class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748283/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-after-ajax-form-submission

Comment: Ajax calls cannot redirect. You need to redirect in the success callback. But you would be better off doing a normal submit

Comment: Thanks Stephen and gokul ! This means if we are using AJAX, only option is redirect it from AJAX callback option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect to a page using js you can use

```
window.location.href = 'your url here'
```

Hope that help.
You Need to add this in your success callback or else a normal form submit can be used

Comment: Well this is handled from JS side. I was searching a way to redirect to other page from controller in success condition. For failure condition, it should return JSon result redirect to AJAX method.

Comment: You can use RedirectToAction