# HTML pages won't change after POST call in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm totally new in Javascript and NodeJS. I'm setting up super simple login page with Login button. When I click on the button, it supposes to invoke javascript file which will call ajax POST. Once the POST call came in to the express app.post, I can see that it passed inside the code block, but my HTML page won't change

I'm not sure if this is the problem with HTML side or JS side or NodeJS side.

Node server:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.url + " :: " + request.method);    
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/pages/login.html'));
}.);

app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.url + " :: " + request.method);
  response.redirect('/home');           
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.url + " :: " + request.method);
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/pages/index.html'));
  response.end();
});
```

login.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
   scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="js/login.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
      <form class="login-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button onclick="runAuth()">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
 </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
   scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   Index
</body>
</html>
```

js/login.js :

```
function runAuth() {

var postRun = $.ajax({
    url: "/auth",
    type: "POST",
    body: 
    {
        "data" : "Hello World"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    contentType: "application/json",
    });
}
```

When I click the button, it shows this in the console

```
/ :: GET
/auth :: POST
/? :: GET
/home :: GET
```

Seems like it loops back to the login page again then go to index page?
I can see the the code inside /auth and /home got executed, but my browser screen still show first Login HTML page

Comment: the problem is that you do an ajax call. in network you should look at the response headers which tell to redirect. In your ajax call, you need to look the response, and if the response contains redirection headers, then you use `document.location.href=newUrl;` to redirect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748283/how-to-redirect-user-to-another-page-after-ajax-form-submission

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

Since you are using AJAX call, you have to change the url from your **frontend**.

```
window.location.href = response.url;
```

and in your **server** response, you have to pass the exact url.

```
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/templates/views/dashboard.html'));
```

and importantly you should **remove the following line**, as this stops sending response to the user.

```
response.end()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some actions in your `ajax` call.
You need to add `success` and `error` call back functions to your `ajax`.
`success` is called when your api returns 200 and login is done successfully. `error` is called when the login fails.

```
var postRun = $.ajax({
    url: "/auth",
    type: "POST",
    body: 
    {
        "data" : "Hello World"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
         // redirect to index page
         window.location.href = "index.html"
    },
    error: function (error) {
         // show error in your html
    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using routes to handle your navigation between files/url's and plain AJAX request using jQuery you cannot redirect from the server. Instead you must redirect from within the handled response inside your browser so add indeed a succes Handler/method and there redirect to the returned url from the back or read the response headers and when it indicates redirect to a specific url. Returning a desired path/url is more flexible since a dynamic url can be returned. Always best practice that on POST or GET for that matter you add response handlers success and error...